# Как исправить ошибку из-за toast?

Tags: java, android, android-toast

У меня в приложении при некоторых обстоятельствах показывается поле toast. Я сделал так, что при закрытии приложения это поле (если оно показывается в момент закрытия) исчезало. Но теперь при закрытии приложения, когда toast не показывается, возникает ошибка.
Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить.
485 строка — строка с if.

```
2019-03-28 18:39:50.634 12998-12998/ru.BigApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.BigApp, PID: 12998
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {ru.BigApp/ru.BigApp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.Toast.getView()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4091)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap24(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1627)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.Toast.getView()' on a null object reference
        at ru.BigApp.MainActivity.onStop(MainActivity.java:485)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1374)
        at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:7150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4140) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap24(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1627) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (problem.getView() != null) {
        if (problem.getView().isShown()){
            problem.cancel();
        }
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override
protected void onStop () {
    if (problem.getView() != null) {
        if (problem.getView().isShown()){
            problem.cancel();
        }
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: какая ошибка? и достаточно делать это только в одном из методов завершения жизненного цикла, лучше в onStop()

Comment: if( problem.getView() != null &&  problem.getView().isShown() )

Comment: когда toast не показывается, его вообще нет и вы обращаетесь к несуществующему объекту за его состоянием, получая NPE. Перед проверкой состояния нужно проверить  сам объект на null

Comment: Если я всё правильно поменял, то всё равно не работает.

Comment: если вы о втором комментарии, то не правильно. вы вызываете метод несуществующего объекта, надо проверять сам объект: `problem != null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
@Override
protected void onStop () {
if (problem != null && problem.getView() != null && problem.getView().isShown()) {
        problem.cancel();
}
super.onStop();
}
```

из OnDestroy уберите этот же метод.

И проверьте нужна ли вам эта проверка

```
problem.getView() != null && problem.getView().isShown()
```

возможно достаточно будет этой

```
problem != null
```

Comment: да, проверки problem != null вполне достаточно, спасибо